# Passing variables between pages

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to implement a two step approach to addding data to a table, for example in my table companies...

I have created 2 PHP pages, called step 1 and step 2, step 1 collects basic information like company name, then the idea is step 2 will collect more specific information like address.

When I save my step 1 page, it redirects to step 2, but I cant figure out how to pass some form of session variable so that page 2 knows what the companyid is.

any ideas

Comment: You said it yourself: [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: Yeah, I second @MarcB .Put them on session variables

Answer (score 1):

save it in a SESSION variable
in page1 use this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id']= $id; //the id to pass
```

and in the page2 you can access $_SESSION['id'] directly

Answer (score 0):

How to store data in a `$_SESSION` :

First of all make sure `session_start()` has been called on top of your page.

Store the value in the session:

```
$_SESSION['paramX'] = 'X';
```

How to get the $_SESSION variable:

```
$paramX = $_SESSION['paramX']
```

A tip to check what's in $_SESSION:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

OR

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```